# What plugin versions for Android Project are not compatible

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-room

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfMKA.png)Here is my build graddle for project

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_ui_version = '1.2.0'
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.0' apply false
}
```

And here is my build graddle for app

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'com.google.devtools.ksp' version '1.8.0-1.0.8'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.assignment1'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.assignment1"
        minSdk 31
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.7'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.2.0'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.6.1'
    //noinspection GradleDependency
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_ui_version"
    //noinspection GradleDependency
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    //noinspection GradleDependency
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_ui_version"
    //noinspection GradleDependency
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_ui_version"
    //noinspection GradleDependency
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_ui_version"

    def nav_version = "2.5.3"

    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:$nav_version"
    def room_version = "2.5.0"

    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

    // To use Kotlin annotation processing tool (kapt)
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    // To use Kotlin Symbol Processing (KSP)
    ksp "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

}
```

I've been trying to use Room plugin. Required parts of plugin were visible in code and I could user them. But when I try to launch the project it fails and gives the error from image. I've launched the project several times before adding new plugins, but now it's unavailable

Comment: did you try re-downloading the dependencies? and restarting IDE after clearing the Cache? The error above doesn't seem to be invoked by room implementations

Comment: I'd suggest using only ksp or kapt not both and if you are not going to be using java then omit `annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"` *(although this can be used, at least with kapt)*